# SWT Browser in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, browser, swt

Is SWT Browser included to standard eclipse installation or I've to install it additionally ?
And if where can I find pack for SWT.

Answer (score 1):

This really does have a lot of good info:

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php

You will need to choose between Webkit and Gecko depending on your requirements. If it's Gecko, you will need to have XULRunner, which is the independent runtime for Gecko that provides the Java XPCOM interfaces.

SWT can be downloaded standalone, but it will not include XULRunner. You'll have to package XULRunner up separately and make that a part of the install.

Answer (score 0):

SWT Browser comes with standard Eclipse SDK
While Eclipse plugin development, there is option for adding Browser in Eclipse plugin code